# Azure KeyVault - How do I get the privatekey stored in keyvault with node?

Tags: jwt, token, sign, azure-keyvault

I need either the secret for HMAC algorithms, or the PEM encoded private key for RSA and ECDSA used to function JWT.sign()

now I get result from function getSecret() and writeStream to a pfx file,then I use openssl get a private key.

```
     const result = await client.getSecret(vaultUri, secretName, secretVersion);
     let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("1.pfx"); 
     writeStream.write(result.value, 'base64');

     openssl pkcs12 -in 1.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out 1.key
     openssl rsa -in 1.key -out 1_pri.key
```

How can i get a private key through the result on node server without openssl?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try? Any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exact private key from .pfx , try this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const forge = require('node-forge');

const file = fs.readFileSync("<path of your .pfx file>");
const p12Der = forge.util.decode64(file.toString('base64'));
const pkcs12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);
const pkcs12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(pkcs12Asn1, '<your .pfx password>');

const { key } = pkcs12.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag })[
  forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag
][0];

const pemPrivate = forge.pki.privateKeyToPem(key);

console.log(pemPrivate);
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it's worked on pemPrivate, then i trying to similarity do publicKeyToPem,it warning me can't use the key of pemPrivate used.How can i do to export a public key ？

Comment: Hi @hooray2015, glad to know this issue has been solved , pls mark this as an answer so that it will help others who has similar issue . If you have any further issue , pls post another question with details and I'll assist you when I see it . Thanks !